# C++ Start Process / Application

Tags: c++

I have a dll source file, I want to create a function in it, which call an exe.

The exe is in the Data/Common/PPI.exe How can I start this from the c++ code?
I tryed with CreateProcess and ShellExec, can anybody create an example for me to know how to make it, with this path and with this exe name.

I dont want to add the full directory path because if its changed or something I need to rebuild the exe... so the dll is in the root folder the dll call this function and the function start the Data/common/PPI.exe, thats it all.

Comment: There are tons of simple examples of using CreateProcess on the web, either you didn't search for them or you need to explain why they didn't work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try the system command like this

```
system(".\\Data\\Common\\PPI.exe")
```

and you need to include this:

```
#include <windows.h>
```

Comment: `.` is the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory#In_operating_systems), which is not guaranteed to be the same as the directory where the `.dll` itself resides.

Comment: that's correct the dll take the exe path, I think the only way to get the path from registry or ini where the path of dll

Comment: `the dll take the exe path` Not sure what you mean by that. To give an example, suppose `C:\dll\op.exe` is an executable which loads the `C:\dll\op.dll` where the OP writes `system(".\\Data\\Common\\PPI.exe");`. Further suppose that `op.exe` is launched from a different directory e.g. from the cmd prompt `C:\temp>C:\dll\op.exe`. Then the `system` call will try (and fail) to locate `ppi.exe` in `C:\temp\data\common` while the OP appears to say that it needs to look for it at `C:\dll\data\common` instead.

Comment: that what I wanted to say that you are correct, the exe current path it´s passed to the dll, even more that what you say, if the exe change the current path on the code and call the function on the dll it will be the new changed path, even if the dll change current path will chane the exe also.

Comment: Still not sure what you mean by `the exe current path it´s passed to the dll`. What I meant in the previous comment is that the OP appears to be asking about how to launch an `.exe` with a relative path rooted at [GetModuleFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx) while your `system` call assumes a relative path rooted at [GetCurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934.aspx). Those two are not necessarily the same.

Comment: Yeah I mean the GetCurrentDirectory and SetCurrentDirectory

Comment: Sorry I added totally bad tag. My application is in vb (Shellexec createprocess..:D)

Comment: This answer was completely wrong, even if the question had been correctly tagged [c++].

Comment: So, sorry the question was right I am just retard. :)

Comment: Is it possible to call system() without the window? So hide the cmd window which come up?

Comment: WinExec();
I think I find it!